# Totally Legit Signing Key <mallory@example.org>

Tags: security, gpg, authentication, key-authentication, cryptography

I run:

```
gpg --list-keys
```

I get:

```
pub   rsa1024 2014-01-26 [C]
      <REMOVED>
uid           [ unknown] Totally Legit Signing Key <mallory@example.org>
```

Can this be dangerous? What is this? The address mallory@example.org is confusing.

Comment: It seems I got this by running: gpg --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-key <SOME_KEY> : https://www.reallinuxuser.com/how-to-verify-your-linux-mint-iso-image-file/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mallory keys were keys added to demonstrate that short key identifiers are easily spoofable. See [this GnuPG discussion](https://dev.gnupg.org/T4136) and [this oss-sec post](https://seclists.org/oss-sec/2018/q3/174) for details.

Unless you’re actively maintaining your OpenPGP web of trust, or validating OpenPGP signatures without checking the keys separately, you can ignore this.

Comment: By "checking the keys separately" you mean I should validate that I have the correct .asc files by downloading them from multiple sources? Maybe I don't understand your post.

Comment: Essentially, if you care about the identity associated with a key, then you need to be able to validate that somehow. That used to be done using the web of trust (with caveats), nowadays it’s more about continuity — *i.e.* you obtain a key at some point, and that key continues to be used to sign artefacts for a long time. If you just download a file, its signature, and the key from the same place at the same time, then it doesn’t tell you anything more than a checksum from the same origin.